# How does maya know, what the output mesh of your MPxNode is?

Tags: python, c++, maya

When using a [PolyModifierNode](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_split_u_v_cmd_2poly_modifier_node_8h_example_html), the node has a `inMesh` and a `outMesh` attribute/plug, where the `inMesh` is hidden and replaced by the `outMesh`. 
But a general [MPxNode](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_px_node_html) may have many inputs and outputs, which can be networked in complicated ways.

My problem in understanding the structure of the MPxNode is, that I do not see in which way maya knows, which objects from the input are transformed into which output objects.
I would have expected something like the `outMesh` from the last node in the graph connected to some `SceneRenderer.inputMeshes` plug, but maya seems to automatically detect in some way which unused `outMesh` plugs should be rendered.

Finally I want to write a node, which gets an array of input meshes and an additional control mesh and should output an array of modified meshes, which replaces the original meshes.

I am using calculations where all objects in the group influence each other, so it cannot be done one by one. It would be possible to use one node per input, but the compute function would need to trigger the computation on all other input meshes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maya doesn't detect unconnected plugs. Instead, it evaluates on demand when something in the network of nodes changes and forces re-evaluations where necessary. You set up the conditions it cares about when you initialize a node using `MPxNode::attributeAffects()`  or its Python equivalent.  Changes to an input will be pushed downstream by other nodes as needed; when a change comes in to your node it will call the `MPxNode::compute compute()` passing the appropriate plug as an argument.  Your node will then update its outputs, passing them along the chain to other nodes.

You probably don't want to make your node take an array of input nodes an return an array of outputs.  It's simpler and more maya-esque to make a node which modifies only one node at a time. That helps localizes chnges in the dependency graph and makes your scene run faster.

Comment: So i need to construct the output mesh myself, i.e. in the command which constructs the node? I need to have a common node, because the objects are influencing each other in a way, which cannot be computed one after another. I would have liked to have a node for transforms (i.e. groups) or even better for sets, but this doesn't seem to work well. Sets cannot be reparented and i had problems using a node with a transform.

Comment: Another short question: Is there a common way (or maybe some example code) how a typicial node hides the original (from view and in the outliner) and creates the result? Is it removed from DAG or just hidden in some way?

Comment: In this case, you should do all your geometry operations in object space so that you change the contents of the geometryShape, leaving the transform hierarchy alone.  If you really need to manage multiple shapes at once you can make a multi attribute.  I'd try outputting just one mesh and then using a plain old Maya `polySeparate` node to split it up again, instead of managing multiple output meshes.

The other thing is -- does this need to be a node at all? It's much easier in general to make commands or scripts.

Comment: Its part of a way more complex project. We need to project there values from some mesh around the objects onto the objects. I try to use a structure with one node per object and two inputs, one for the wrapping mesh and one for the object mesh.

Comment: @allo you can either work with the system or against it. If you work against ot then you will feel like fighting every step on your way.

Comment: Currently i am starting to use a structure, which is different from both approaches. Anyway the answer helped at lot. When i asked the question, i did not fully know how a node works and thought it was a much more rigid contruct than it is.